# Уникальная комбинация двух значений в таблице методами SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql

Есть таблица. В ней столбцы `var1 var2`. Нужно добавлять туда записи. Возможно ли реализовать только на SQL проверки на существование такой записи? Просто сами по себе значения `var1` и `var2` повторяться будут, а вот вместе не должны. Например так:

`1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 2
2 | 3`

При добавлении если такая комбинация есть, то ничего не делать.
Возможно ли такое? Или без средств другого языка не обойтись?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE
        `users` (
       `var1` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       `var2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       UNIQUE(`var1`, `var2`)
   )
```

Ссыль по теме http://mysql.ru/docs/man/CREATE_TABLE.html

Comment: Надо просто в таблице обьявить какие поля будут уникальными и ненадо будет нагружать базу лишними запросами, она все сделает за вас

Comment: При попытке нарушения уникальности во время вставки данных в такую таблицу БД выбросит исключение. Не факт, что это то, что нужно тому, кто спросил.

Comment: А надо проверять что возвращает mysql и обрабатывать исключения и тогда проблем не будет. Нет панацеи от всех проблем, надо с ними бороться по мере поступления)

Answer (score 2):

Если нужен именно запрос, который выполнится без ошибок

```
insert into table
select one, two from 
(select 1 as one, 2 as two) t1
    left outer join table t2 on t2.var1=t1.one and t2.var2=t1.two
where t2.var1 is null and t2.var2 is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно согласен с уважаемым [@Barton](/users/1971/barton). Добавлю не дословную цитату из книги Томаса Кайта, вице-президента Oracle. Если в СУБД предусмотрена некая опция, то ни в коем случае не пытайтесь заменить ее собственным программным кодом: всегда получится хуже!!!

Answer (score -1):

конечно, надо написать ХП, которая во входящем параметре принимает значение, которое стоит вставить в таблицу, но перед вставкой селектом проверяется ее наличие.

```
    insert into table(row) select val1 from other_table where not exist (
select 1 from table where row=val1)
```

возможно ошибся, но как-то так должно быть =)